# pagination among child nodes in dynatree

Tags: jquery-dynatree

In a dynatree or fancy tree how can we show the childnodes with pagination?

can you please give an example in a spring boot application of how can we show the course with topics and subtopics in  a tree form, here topics and subtopics will be shown in a paginated way

thanks & regards

implementing pagination while showing the child nodes in a dynatree

example at a time showing only 10 child nodes

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.